# Symfony2 Doctrine: syntax error, unexpected 'function', expecting 'identifier'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm working with symfony2 and I'm using Doctrine to create entities from an existing Database. It seems like everything goes fine except this Syntax Error:

syntax error, unexpected 'function', expecting 'identifier'

I've been searching for a solution and it seems most of the time a typo is the cause. But this code is all being generated by Doctrine and I'm not seeing any typo's ...
Here is the class where the error is showing up, specifically at 'Class Function':

```
<?php

namespace IntoPeople\DatabaseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Function
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Function")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Function
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", length=250, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


}
```

Comment: how about trying some other class name? 'function' is reserved word in php and by definition you shouldn't use those as class name

Comment: Ok that was the reason! Solved it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually thanks to quoting, you can use it regardless of it being a reserved word: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

```
/**
 * Function
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="`Function`")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class Function
 {
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I wasn't allowed to use 'Function' as a table name .. Changed it and everything working now.